# How do I send "true" or "false" via a form using the Kendo UI Switch component?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik

I've been working with the Kendo UI and trying to work with their Switch Component. The component is binded to the my application through the MVVM framework.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/switch

So my code looks like this.

HTML:

```
 <input data-role="kendo.mobile.ui.Switch" data-role="switch" id="Active" data-type="boolean" data-name="active" data-checked="false" data-bind="events: {change: changeActiveFilter }"/>
```

JS CODE:

```
    let viewModel = new kendo.observable({

        changeActiveFilter: function(e){
            console.log(e.sender.value());
        }

    });

    new kendo.bind($(".container"), viewModel);
```

When I run this code and click on the switch in my browser, the console reports this as True when on and False when off. This is good and what I want.

But when I submit the form that this component is tied to, the application just reports that the value is "on" and nothing else. Despite whether the switch is "true" or "false"

How do I pass the correct value to my back end?

Comment: Is your app made with PHP ?

Comment: No it's all done in Javascript

Comment: Where you submit the form to ? Nodejs ?

Comment: Yes, it's running on Node.ja